# How to Create or edit a txt file in a folder in Java?

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to make save files for a game i'm making, these files will have multiple txt files in them. My problem is that both the folder and the txt file wont create themselves in the directory I specify, here is the code for the folder:

```
File folde = new File("c:/Users/Mike/Desktop/Saves/bob/" + save);
    try{
    if (!folde.exists()) {
        if (folde.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println("Created new save file");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Did not create new save file");
        }
    }
    }finally{
        System.out.println("Folder found.");
    }
```

Here is the code for the file:

```
try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("c:/Users/Mike/Desktop/javafiles/Saves/" + save + "/Stats.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(Stats.Health);
        writer.println(Stats.Strength);
        writer.println(Stats.Constitution);
        writer.println(Stats.Dexterity);
        writer.println(Stats.Inteligence);
        writer.println(Stats.Wisdom);
        writer.println(Stats.Charisma);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println("Could not create save file.");

    }
```

And here is the entire Class:

```
package files.maintain;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import vars.all.*;

public class SaveFile {
MainStart Start = new MainStart();
Stats Stats = new Stats();
public void save(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What should I save as?");
    String save = in.nextLine();

    File folde = new File("c:/Users/Dave/Desktop/Saves/bob/" + save);
    try{
    if (!folde.exists()) {
        if (folde.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println("Created new save file");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Did not create new save file");
        }
    }
    }finally{
        System.out.println("Folder found.");
    }
    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("c:/Users/Dave/Desktop/javafiles/Saves/" + save + "/Stats.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println(Stats.Health);
        writer.println(Stats.Strength);
        writer.println(Stats.Constitution);
        writer.println(Stats.Dexterity);
        writer.println(Stats.Inteligence);
        writer.println(Stats.Wisdom);
        writer.println(Stats.Charisma);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println("Could not create save file.");

    }
}
}
```

The Response i'm getting from the console is:

- What should I save as?
- **bob**
- Folder found.
- Could not create save file.*

My input is in bold,
I checked this website: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-directory-in-java/
And the java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html
But that didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: You're hiding the IOException behind an unhelpful error message. Add `x.printStackTrace();` to the catch block, and you'll know the reason of the exception. Also, the first part makes sure a folder exists, but the second part doesn't write into it. Kinda strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make paths consistent if not the same.  Instead of using string constants, use a single Java `File` object.  You are using these 2 inconsistent prefixes:

```
"c:/Users/Dave/Desktop/Saves/bob/"
"c:/Users/Dave/Desktop/javafiles/Saves/"
```

Also, you need to improve your exception handling and reporting.  Log as much information as you can about the original exception and the corrective (or emergency) action your program is taking.